# FFMPEG: Multithread decoding deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, ffmpeg, deadlock, decode

I'm using FFMPEG to decode H264 stream from IP Camera. There are many cameras so I used multithread with FFMPEG.

I registered multithread with FFMPEG by the below code

```
static int lockmgr(void **mtx, enum AVLockOp op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
    case AV_LOCK_CREATE:
        *mtx = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
        if (!*mtx)
            return 1;
        return !!pthread_mutex_init((pthread_mutex_t*)*mtx, NULL);
    case AV_LOCK_OBTAIN:
        return !!pthread_mutex_lock((pthread_mutex_t*)*mtx);
    case AV_LOCK_RELEASE:
        return !!pthread_mutex_unlock((pthread_mutex_t*)*mtx);
    case AV_LOCK_DESTROY:
        pthread_mutex_destroy((pthread_mutex_t*)*mtx);
        free(*mtx);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

av_lockmgr_register(lockmgr)
```

In each thread that connect to IP Camera, the code for decoding H264 stream from that IP Camera is below

```
 int DecodeStream()
 {
     try
    {
        InitForH264Stream();

        int             bytesDecoded = 0;
        int             frameFinished = 0;
        while (commonGlobal->settings.iPCameraSettigs.isRunningThreadRequestVideo[rtpHeader->cameraInd])
        {
            while (_packet->size > 0)
            {
                // Decode the next chunk of data
                bytesDecoded = avcodec_decode_video2(rtpHeader->pCodecCtx, rtpHeader->pFrame,
                    &frameFinished, _packet);
                // Was there an error?
                if (bytesDecoded < 0)
                {
                    if (rtpHeader->packetPointer != NULL)
                    {
                        _packet->data = rtpHeader->packetPointer;
                        rtpHeader->packetPointer = NULL;
                        av_free_packet(_packet);
                    }
                    return RS_NOT_OK;
                }

                _packet->size -= bytesDecoded;
                _packet->data += bytesDecoded;
                if (rtpHeader->packetPointer != NULL && _packet->size == 0)
                {
                    _packet->data = rtpHeader->packetPointer;
                    rtpHeader->packetPointer = NULL;
                    av_free_packet(_packet);
                }
                if (frameFinished)
                {
                    return RS_OK;
                }
                // Did we finish the current frame? Then we can return
            }
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    av_init_packet(_packet);
                    rtpHeader->th->Reset();
                    int ret = AVERROR(EAGAIN);
                    while (AVERROR(EAGAIN) == ret)
                        ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, _packet);
                    if (ret < 0)
                    {
                        if (ret == AVERROR(AVERROR_EOF) || (pFormatCtx->pb && pFormatCtx->pb->eof_reached))
                        {
                            sprintf(strErr, "Error end of file line %d", __LINE__);
                        }
                        if (pFormatCtx->pb && pFormatCtx->pb->error)
                        {
                            sprintf(strErr, "Error end of file line %d", __LINE__);
                        }
                        _packet->data = NULL;
                        return RS_NOT_OK;
                    }
                    if (_packet->stream_index != rtpHeader->videoStreamInd)
                        av_free_packet(_packet);
                    else
                        rtpHeader->packetPointer = _packet->data;
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    _packet->data = NULL;
                    return RS_NOT_OK;
                }
            } while (_packet->stream_index != rtpHeader->videoStreamInd);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        _packet = NULL;
        commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeLogs("ReceiveRTPBlock() threw an Exception");
        UnInitForH264Stream();
        return RS_NOT_OK;
    }
 }


VOID UnInitForH264Stream()
{
    if (rtpHeader.pCodecCtx != NULL)
        avcodec_close(rtpHeader.pCodecCtx);

    if (pFormatCtx != NULL)
        av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);

    if (rtpHeader.th != NULL)
    {
        delete rtpHeader.th;
        rtpHeader.th = NULL;
    }       

    if (rtpHeader.pFrame != NULL)
        avcodec_free_frame(&rtpHeader.pFrame);

    if (RGBFrame != NULL)
    {
        avcodec_free_frame(&RGBFrame);
        RGBFrame = NULL;            
    }

    if (ConversionContext != NULL)
    {
        sws_freeContext(ConversionContext);
        ConversionContext = NULL;
    }

    if (rgbBuffer != NULL)
    {
        av_free(rgbBuffer);
        rgbBuffer = NULL;
    }   
}
```

- I encountered a deadlock when the function `avcodec_decode_video2()`throw an exception, and then the program was deadlocked when call `UnInitForH264Stream()` at line `avcodec_close(rtpHeader.pCodecCtx);`I have fixed and maybe the funtion `avcodec_decode_video2()` work right (not throw exception).
- But now, sometime I encountered a deadlock when decoding, but I don't know which function that caused the deadlock. Because It's hard to reproduce this bug.

Someone can tell me is there any potential deadlock in my code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[This libav thread](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-November/000896.html) Shows a slightly different implementation of the lock.

Furthermore, you seem to init ffmpeg within your decode function. [This thread here](http://libav-users.943685.n4.nabble.com/Threads-safe-issue-with-ffmpeg-c-td945683.html) seems to point to the conclusion that opening and closing streams is not a thread safe operation even if you declare the lockmgr properly. You should consider moving them to a central, synchronized place where your stream start

Comment: Thank you! This code is summary, the main code was implemented as you said "moving them to a central, synchronized place where your stream start". Can you explain what differences between my code and the above implementation of the lock that you show me?

Comment: i'd remove the * here : if (!*mtx). Also you don't need the !! in front of the pthread functions. !! is usually a C hack for "cast pointer to bool". I think it will return 1 if the pthread function returned 0 which will indicate a failure. I'm not 100% about this

Comment: nvm, !! should be fine, it will return 1 for all non 0 values